# psycopg2 batch execute_values update with dynamic WHERE

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to do a batch UPDATE .. WHERE with psycopg2's execute_values method. The [documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html) only offers this example:

```
execute_values(cur,"""UPDATE test SET v1 = data.v1 FROM (VALUES %s) AS data (id, v1) WHERE test.id = data.id""", [(1, 20), (4, 50)])
```

Given that execute_values can only have one param %s, how do I get `data.id` to be anything other than a fixed value? How can I use a variable value to qualify the WHERE part of the statement to UPDATE multiple rows?

Comment: In the example 1 and 4 are the id values that `UPDATE`  v1 to 20 and 50 respectively.  That is handled by the `FROM (VALUES %s) AS data (id, v1) WHERE test.id = data.id` where the values in the tuples become `id` and `val` in the `(VALUES %s)` portion.

Comment: Are you saying that the AS statement is used to name the tuple in that iteration so it can be referenced later in the SQL statement by that name?

Comment: Yes, it is easy enough to test: `select * FROM (VALUES(1, 40)) AS data (id, v1); 1 | 40`

Comment: Thank you so much. Do  you know if I can also use the psycopg.sql.SQL(...)format(sql.Identifier() method to add column variability to execute_values()? Or is that method only possible with a normal psycopg engine.execute() method.

Comment: Yes. You will need to supply a template to execute_values() though. Read the docs for how this is done. I'm not at computer presently, so that is all I can offer.

Comment: On second thought I am supposing it is practically not possible because I would not be able to variably reference a column depending on the tuple accessed per iteration.

Comment: You don't have to use tuples, you can use named parameters and dicts. To determine the possibility you need to update your question to give a real life example of what you are trying to achieve.